# gedit missing spell check database

Tags: spell-check, gedit, debian-squeeze

Spell check is installed and enabled in gedit, but the dictionary seems to be missing.  When I enable autocheck spelling every word is highlighted as incorrect (and yes, some of them are spelled correctly).

I'm running a fairly fresh copy of Debian Squeeze and I'm not sure if it's a distro issue or otherwise.  I can't seem to find any hints as to what the issue might be through Google.  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I was missing the aspell package.

In my case..

```
sudo apt-get install aspell-en
```

or more generally...

```
sudo apt-get install aspell-lang
```